# Network server with raspberry pi

Tags: server, networking

Could anyone give me a step by step guide on how to create and run a file server using a raspberry pi. I'm newvto raspberry pi
I want to be able to store and share main video and music between my PC and laptop, plus Samsung smart TV.
Thanks for any help, anyone can give me.

Comment: The smart TV is the limiting factor in the sense that the other devices are probably more flexible.  You need to find out exactly what protocols the TV will work with.   It probably supports [DLNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Living_Network_Alliance), so you would want to set-up a DLNA server on the pi; searching "linux dlna server" should turn up some stuff ([e.g](http://elinux.org/DLNA_Open_Source_Projects)).   If you are using Raspbian, it is a normal GNU/Linux distribution, so do not limit your searches by including "Raspberry Pi" in the search terms.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://bbrks.me/rpi-minidlna-media-server/) guide is likely what you want for the TV;

```
sudo -i
apt-get update && \
apt-get upgrade && \
apt-get install minidlna && \
update-rc.d minidlna defaults && \
echo -e "media_dir=R,/path/to/Files\nfriendly_name=Raspberry Pi\ninotify=yes" >> /etc/minidlna.conf && \
service minidlna restart
```

Then search for how to setup samba for your other devices.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will try this over the next couple of months